# IOS:upload a image to server Php From ios devices is Not Working?

Tags: php, ios

**i used This Code for devices:**

```
    NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/phd-admin//testing.php"];

   NSData *imageData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    ;
    NSLog(@"data length %d",[imageData length]);
   // UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];

    if (imageData != nil)
    {
     NSString   *filenames = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Deal.png"];      //set name here
        NSLog(@"%@", filenames);
        NSString *urlString = @"http://localhost/php-admin//receiveFile.php";

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

        NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
        NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
        [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

        NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"filenames\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[filenames dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"Deal.png" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        // setting the body of the post to the reqeust
        [request setHTTPBody:body];
        // now lets make the connection to the web
        NSLog(@"requereting %@",request);
        NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
        NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(returnString);
          NSLog(@"response %@",returnString);
        NSLog(@"finish");
```

i Used This Code For Server Side:

```
<?php
$myparam = $_POST['userfile'];     //getting image Here
$mytextLabel= $_POST['filenames'] ;  //getting textLabe Here
echo $myparam;
echo $mytextLabel; 
$target_path = "upload/";
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['myfile']['name']);  
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['myfile']['name']) . " has been uploaded";
} else {
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!".$myparam."val".$mytextLabel;
}
?>
```

but it is not working?

pls suggest your answer.
thank,s.

Comment: Please post errors you are getting.

Comment: no error is come.but all the php echo will is empty.

Comment: Var_dump($_POST) And var_dump($_FILES['userfile']) in PHP

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have too many lines there, do not need it all. Try just this instead all your `appendData`:

```
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", filenames] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Your **PHP**:

```
<?php
    $file = $_FILES['userfile'];
    $target_path = "upload/" . $label;

    if (move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
        echo "The file ". basename($file['name']) . " has been uploaded";
    } else {
        echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!" . var_dump($file);
    }
?>
```

Try this way.